# GetTextExtentPoint32 returns wrong widths with specific characters

Tags: c++, winapi, width, gdi

I'm trying to use GetTextExtentPoint32 on C++ to get the width of some characters, one at a time. However, the function returns wrong results for special characters, like 0x14, usually half the size of it printed on screen with ExtTextOut. Here's an example:

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);    
SelectObject(hdc,font);    
SIZE sz;     
char c=0x14;    
GetTextExtentPoint32(hdc,&c,1,&sz); //function returns sz.cx equal to 3 instead of 6
```

Same thing happens with GetCharWidth32:

```
int result;    
GetCharWidth32(hdc,0x14,0x14,&result); //result equals to 3, while the character on screen is 6px wide
```

Any clues where's my mistake? Thank you in advance.

EDIT: it seems GetTextExtentPoint32 finds inaccurate widths for all ASCII characters less than 32. I found out that DrawText with DT_CALCRECT flag computes all characters just fine. The only drawback is that DrawText consumes way more CPU than GetTextExtentPoint32.

```
HDC hdc=GetDC(hWnd);
RECT rect;
rect.left=0; rect.top=0;
DrawText(hdc,"\x14",1,&rect,DT_CALCRECT); //rect.right = character width
```

Comment: Why you don't check if GetTextExtentPoint32 returns FALSE?

Comment: Are you calling GetTextExtentPoint32A or GetTextExtentPoint32W?  (I presume it is GetTextExtentPoint32A, because of the `&c` parameter.)

Comment: I'm using GetTextExtentPoint32A and return value is TRUE. The function works nicely with printable characters like letters and numbers. My only problem is with some special characters like 0x14.

Comment: The dialog box  takes "dialog box units", not pixels. So you have to a conversion first: use [GetDialogBaseUnits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdialogbaseunits) ,similar discussion:[GetTextExtentPoint32() returns wrong value](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cda13285-7685-42f5-939a-f0adcc7afbd5/gettextextentpoint32-returns-wrong-value?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues).

Comment: I think this should not be limited to special characters. All characters should return inaccurate values with GetTextExtentPoint32.

Comment: Why are you executing `SelectObject(hdc,font);` twice with no executable code in between?